# How to translate the origin from (0,0) to (x,y) with a matrix multiplication?

Tags: r, matrix, rotation, transform, matrix-multiplication

I have a 2 by 4 matrix `coor` that define four points: `(0,0)`, `(a,0)`, `(a, -b)` and `(a-c, -b)` of a line on the plane:

```
a<-3; b<-1; c<-1
coor <- matrix(0,2,4)
coor <- t(matrix(c(0,0, a,0, a,-b, a-c, -b), nrow=2));
```

I have added to the `coor` matrix the 3rd column is '1's in order to use this matrix in multiplication.

```
coor <- cbind(coor, 1)
```

I need to 1) translate the origin from `(0,0)` to the fourth point with coordinats `(a-c,-b)` and 2) rotate the line on the angle `alpha`:

```
# translation matrix
I <- matrix(0,3,3); diag(I) <- 1

I[1, 3] <- -coor[4, 1]
I[2, 3] <- -coor[4, 2]

alpha = -pi/2

# rotation matrix
M <- matrix(c(cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 0,
             -sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0,
                 0,          0, 1), nrow=3)


coor1 <- matrix()
coor1 <- coor %*% I %*% M %*% solve(I)
```

Result of two operations is:

```
> cbind(coor1[,1], coor1[,2])
            [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.00000e+00    0
[2,] 1.83691e-16    3
[3,] 1.00000e+00    3
[4,] 1.00000e+00    2
```

Expected result is:

```
> coor2 <- matrix(c(2,-1, 2,2, 3,2, 3,1),nrow=2); t(coor2);
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   -1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    3    1
```

Plot with original points and results is below. In the graph I have grouped the given points in the red line, where a, b, c are lengths of corresponding line segments.

```
plot(t(coor[1,]), t(coor[2,]), col='red', type= 'l', xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(-1,3), xlab='x', ylab='y')
points(round(cbind(coor1[,1], coor1[,2]),2), col='green', type= 'l')
points(t(coor2), col='blue', type= 'l')
```

[image]

**Question.** How to make the matrix multiplication `coor %*% I %*% M %*% solve(I)` correctly in order to move first point of line from `(0,0)` to `(a-c, -b)`?

**Edit.**

[Combining translation and rotation](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node99.html)

The full code:

```
a<-3; b<-1; c<-1
coor <- matrix(0,2,4)
coor <- t(matrix(c(0,0, a,0, a,-b, a-c, -b), nrow=2));

coor <- cbind(coor, 1) 

# translation matrix
I <- matrix(0,3,3); diag(I) <- 1

I[1, 3] <- -coor[4, 1]
I[2, 3] <- -coor[4, 2]
alpha = -pi/2

# rotation matrix
M <- matrix(c(cos(alpha), sin(alpha), 0,
             -sin(alpha), cos(alpha), 0,
                 0,          0, 1), nrow=3)


coor1 <- matrix()
coor1 <- coor %*% I %*% M %*% solve(I) 
coor2 <- matrix(c(2,-1, 2,2, 3,2, 3,1),nrow=2)

plot(coor[,1], coor[,2], col='red', type= 'l', xlim=c(-3,6), ylim=c(-2,6), xlab='x', ylab='y')
points(x=coor1[,1], y=coor1[,2], col='green', type= 'l')
points(t(coor2), col='blue', type= 'l')
```

Comment: Can you clarify? For one thing `coor` is not 3x3 so it's unclear what you mean by "defining vectors in the plane", since the plane is two dimensional and that matrix could refer to either 3 or 4 "dimensions". For another thing it's unclear what is being asked. Are you just asking how matrix multiplication works?

Comment: @42, I have re-formulated the question.

Comment: I'm confused. (a) The convention is to apply a transformation matrix `M` to a vector `x` from the left, `M %*% x = result`, but you are seeking to right-multiply instead. Is there a reason, or is this a mistake? If this is deliberate, you will (I believe) need to transpose the conventional mappings. (b) Your diagram shows a translation only, and your "expected result" seems to match up with the diagram, but you compare it to code for a translation and a rotation. Do you have the expected result including the rotation? (c) `I` is the identity matrix, please use another letter for translation...

Comment: (d) Why are you using `I %*% M %*% solve(I)`? You say "translate and rotate" which would be `I %*% M`, (or, using standard conventions for left-multiplication, `M %*% I %*% x`). Adding a `solve(I)` to the mix suggests you want to undo the translation after the rotation. But you don't seem to mention that in your text anywhere, so it is confusing.

Comment: So, all that said, I think what you want is (using the objects as you've defined them, but standard left-multiplication of the transformations) `M %*% I %*% t(coor)`. If you want start with `coor` and right-multiply, transpose everything: `coor %*% t(I) %*% t(M)`.

Answer (score 0):

The own answer on the question:

```
a <- 3; b <-1 ; c <- 1

coor <- matrix(0, 2, 4)
coor <- t(matrix(c(0,0, a,0, a,-b, a-c, -b), nrow=2));
coor <- cbind(coor, 1)

alpha = -pi/2

coor1 <- matrix(0, 3, 3)

# new origin (x, y)
x <- coor[4,1]; y <- coor[4,2]

T <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
T <- matrix(c(cos(alpha), sin(alpha),  x,
             -sin(alpha), cos(alpha),  y,
                       0,          0,  1), nrow=3);
coor1 <- coor %*% T

plot(coor[,1], coor[,2], col='red', type= 'l', xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(-1,2), xlab='x', ylab='y')
points(round(cbind(coor1[,1], coor1[,2]),2), col='green', type= 'l')
```

[image]

Comment: Code only answers are considered insufficient in SO